# pandas: sum() return the infinite value

Tags: python, pandas, sum, infinite

I have a DataFrame with the datatype of the column is float16 which maximum value is 65536. When I call the sum() in pandas to sum all the value of this column, I get infinite "inf" values as the value exceeds the range.

This is a sample of the input data and output of sum:

[image: input sample and output]

Since the data type of the output value of the sum() function automatically follows the data type of the column, I would like to ask if there is any way to convert the value of sum in pandas to avoid the infinitive value?

Comment: Try to share some input data. Makes life easier.

Comment: Can you share the input data as @AntonvBR  asked, How you are using the `sum()` also if you could illustrate the DataFrame that will help to reproduce.

Comment: there is only way to avoid `(dtype=np.float16).sum(dtype=np.float64)`

Comment: @pygo I tried it but it still doesn't work :(

Comment: @biendltb, there is bug opened for this i have included that in my answer section.. which is still open, still no solution :(

Comment: @pygo Maybe I have to change the data type of my data which might increase the footprint of my dataset significantly. Thank you man :)

Comment: Now that you have shared data it is easier to try to help. How about `df.groupby('UniqueCarrier').apply(np.sum)['ArrDelay'][:5]`?

Comment: @biendltb, Yes , that will be good approach to go and test for! Good Luck.

Answer (score 2):

The first that comes in mind is to pass a `dtype=np.float64` param.

```
df.sum(axis=1,dtype=np.float64)
```

However this returns a ValueError:

> ValueError: the 'dtype' parameter is not supported in the pandas
>   implementation of sum()

---

Possible workaround:

Use `np.sum()`, the underlying library to pandas, instead and pass dtype.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': [35000.0, 35000.0],
    'col2': [35000.0, 35000.0]
})

df['col1'] = df['col1'].astype(np.float16)
df['col2'] = df['col2'].astype(np.float16)

#print(df.sum(axis=1)) # --> results in inf 
#print(df.sum(axis=1,dtype=np.float64)) # --> results in error message
print(np.sum(df.values, dtype=np.float64, axis=1)) # --> works
```

Comment: As I need to combine the sum() function of pandas with the other pandas functions so I can't use the np.sum here. Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no solution so far , possible workaround may be as @Anton vBR.
However there is already a bug with this When running reductions on dataframe columns of dtype float16, it into a surprising behaviour:

[Already a Bug opened for this on github[(https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/22841)